# Accessing pytest assert message in finalizer

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to generate a custom report with pytest and trying to access the assert message generated by pytest, in the case of a failure, in the finalizer of a global fixture in the conftest.py file. I am able to access the status of the test but I am not able to get the error message.

I would like to access the status message in the following way

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function',autouse = True)
def logFunctionLevel(request):
    start = int(time.time() * 1000)
    def fin():
        stop = int(time.time())
        fo = open("/Users/mahesh.nayak/Desktop/logs/test1.log", "a")
        fo.write(request.cls.__name__ + "." + request.function.__name__ + " " + str(start) + " " + str(stop) + "\n")
```

Any help to access the exception message is appreciated

Thanks

Edit : The answer by Bruno did help. Adding the below lines printed the asserts.

```
  l = str(report.longrepr)
  fo.write(l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can access the exception message from a fixture, but you can implement a custom `pytest_runtest_logreport` hook (untested):

```
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    fo = open("/Users/mahesh.nayak/Desktop/logs/test1.log", "a")
    fo.write('%s (duration: %s)\n' % (report.nodeid, report.duration))
    fo.close()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To access the assert message from a fixture you can follow the documentation here :

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures

Which for your question make something look like that: (untested code)

```
# content of conftest.py

import pytest


 @pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
 def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # set a report attribute for each phase of a call, which can
    # be "setup", "call", "teardown"

    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)


@pytest.fixture
def something(request):
    yield

    # request.node is an "item" because we use the default
    # "function" scope
    error_message= ""
    if request.node.rep_setup.failed:
        print("setting up a test failed!", request.node.nodeid)
        error_message = request.node.rep_setup.longreprtext
    elif request.node.rep_setup.passed:
        if request.node.rep_call.failed:
            print("executing test failed", request.node.nodeid)
            error_message = request.node.rep_call.longreprtext

    fo = open("/Users/mahesh.nayak/Desktop/logs/test1.log", "a")
    if error_message:
        fo.write('%s (duration: %s) - ERROR - %s \n' % (report.nodeid, report.duration,
                                                        error_message))
    else:
        fo.write('%s (duration: %s) - PASSED \n' % (report.nodeid, report.duration))
    fo.close()
```

The main difference with Bruno Oliveira answer, is that *pytest_runtest_logreport* is called for **each** different step of the test ( setup/call/teardown? ), when a fixture can be called **only one time** at the end of the test.